# how to retrive textfield value in selenium if the value is not present in value attributes?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image: Image 1][image: image 2]

I wants to verify value that is present in Display Name field.
After entering First Name Display Name will populates automatically.
display name value is present in front-end but not present in DOM.
I tried with

```
driver.webdriver.findElement(By.id("DisplayName")).getText();
```

and

```
String abc= driver.webdriver.findElement(By.id("DisplayName")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: try this driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DisplayName']")).getText();

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: What was the result of the code you tried?

Comment: I'm getting  "Empty" value.

Comment: @Hiten  there is no issue in xpath or locator. value tag does not contains any value it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DisplayName']")).getAttribute("value");

Hi this works for me...